# what does ask girl for hand mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

Listening to Shop Around by the Miracles, they say:

> Before you ask some girl for her hand now

Well, I completely get the idea that **ask hand**, as in almost all the languages, means somehow be in love relationship, but my question is if it means say i love you or it means would you marry me?

Comment: I have never heard of "ask hand" used in English. Do you have an example?

Comment: @user3169 yes, check [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBJ_sG-OdlU)

Comment: There is no "ask hand" in the lyrics, just "ask some girl for her hand". I get what you meant, but you used "ask hand" in your explanation like that was the actual phrase used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To ask a girl for her hand" means to ask her to marry you.

Comment: Oh Okay thanks, I'd prefer to [Shop Around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBJ_sG-OdlU) B-)

Comment: It could also be a request to dance.

Comment: though most often it is used in the context of a request for marriage.

Comment: (and, to be slightly more specific, it means to ask her to hold out her hand so the man can place an engagement ring on her finger)

Comment: At one point it was traditional for a man to formally ask his fiancee's father for her hand in marriage.  See for example https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/asking-a-womans-father-for-her-hand-in-marriage/